# Phonegap/cordova plugin not fired on remote website

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm building a phonegap/cordova application where the html is coming from a remote source. I'm using the plugins to communicate from the webpage with the native application.

I started building an android variant which is working fine with the plugin. Now I'm adding Windows Phone but cannot manage to get the plugins working from the remote html.

I tried it with the default html page which is a local html page and tried to communicate with the plugin, that's working fine. So my conclusion is that the plugin and call of cordova.exec() are correct.

In my output window I see some messages from where i'm not sure if they influence the behavior i'm seeing:

*CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted

deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

Channel not fired: onPluginsReady

Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
*

Anyone knows if there are issues with the cordova plugins on Windows Phone 8 or how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing and debugging I found out why the plugin is not firing on the remote site, but is working locally.

Phonegap uses different versions of the cordova.js file for every platform. Included the version for Windows Phone on the remote site and the plugin started working (And Andriod stopped working)

Re-thinking about my architecture now with the added knowledge.

Comment: Hi ChristiaanV, pleasecan you share the solution i'm also facing the same issue